# Why is this assembly program segfaulting when I call printf?

Tags: assembly, segmentation-fault, printf, x86-64

The following code is giving me a segmentation fault because of calling printf:

```
            .text
    .global main
main:    
    push %r13
    push %r14
    push %r15
    jmp rest
f:
    pop %rbx
    movq $0, %rax
    push %rbx
    movq $1, %r9
    pushq %r9
    mov $format,%rdi
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    pop %rbx
    call printf
    push %rbx
    movq $1, %r9
    pushq %r9
    mov $format,%rdi
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    pop %rbx
    call printf
    push %rbx
    ret
func:
    pop %rbx
    movq $0, %rax
    push %rbx
    call f
    push %rax
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    .data
    xfunc:    .quad   0
    .text
    mov %r15,xfunc
    ret
rest:
    call func
    push %rax
    mov $format,%rdi
    popq %rsi
    movq %rsi, %r15
    call printf
    mov $0,%rax
    pop %r15
    pop %r14
    pop %r13
    ret
    .data
format:    .string "%lu\n"
```

If i take out the second call printf for printing variable if in label f, there is no segmentation fault. Also if I call the label f directly from rest there is no segmentation fault.

Comment: `printf()` is a variadic function.  This has implications for the expected types of the variable arguments, and, depending on implementation, for  calling conventions.  I'm inclined to guess that you're falling down in one of those areas, but I'm not adept enough at reading assembly to be sure, and there is anyway the implementation dependency to consider.

Comment: @JohnBollinger this same thing happens if I try to print af twice, but not if I print af once, so I don't think it is about arg types :(

Comment: where is your factorial function defined?

Comment: And why add the C tag? That's not related to the C language.

Comment: @anc: **undefined** behaviour implies that it sometimes might work. Read the ABI of your platform.

Comment: @dragosht sorry!! was supposed to be fun.

Comment: @Olaf do you have any suggestions??

Comment: I already stated what you should do.

Comment: Why not show the C code that generates this assembly?

Comment: @FredK: Considering the structure, I somewhat doubt this was generated by a compiler.

Comment: Use the debugger to pinpoint where the fault happens. Usually it is in an aligned vector move, which means you screwed up stack alignment. Your code is unreadable with that mess of pushes and pops, so I can't be bothered to check it statically ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the X86_64 ABI:

```
Register    Usage
%rax        temporary register; with variable arguments
            passes information about the number of vector
            registers used; 1st return register
```

For the case of `printf` the number of vector registers is 0.

Your first call to `printf` sets your `%rax` register to 2 (it is used as a return value).

Just make sure you set it back to `$0` before the second call and that's it ...

Comment: Good catch, I only glanced at the code and seen that `rax` is initially zeroed, so OP clearly knows the rule. But indeed, it's not set for the later invocations.

Comment: Thank you SO MUCH! For some reason I thought that rax was only set when a label within assembly was called, not printf.